# Laravel 9 error Array to string conversion when run seeder

Tags: php, laravel

I have an error on Laravel 9 when run seeder, its say `Array to string conversion`

I have a same seeder type json before this `DataMaster` table, and its working. But when i run DataMasterSeeder, its not working

My seeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\DataMaster;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DataMasterSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //SDU
        DataMaster::create(['formId' => 1, 'userId' => 1, 'kecamatanId' => 1, 'desaId' => null, 'fieldDatas' => [['id' => '1', 'name' => 'jumlah', 'title' => 'Jumlah', 'value' => '4605']], 'level' => 'kecamatan']);
    }
}
```

And my DataMaster migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('data_masters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('formId');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('userId');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('kecamatanId')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('desaId')->nullable();
            $table->json('fieldDatas');
            $table->enum('level', ['kecamatan', 'desa']);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign("formId")->references("id")->on("forms")->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign("userId")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign("kecamatanId")->references("id")->on("kecamatans")->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign("desaId")->references("id")->on("desas")->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

I have another seeder like fieldDatas json field in this DataMaster seeder, and i run it successfully before run DataMaster seeder.

Answer (score 2):

you should encode the field `fieldDatas` before inserting

```php
DataMaster::create([
    'formId' => 1,
    'userId' => 1,
    'kecamatanId' => 1,
    'desaId' => null,
    // here...
    'fieldDatas' => json_encode([['id' => '1', 'name' => 'jumlah', 'title' => 'Jumlah', 'value' => '4605']]),
    'level' => 'kecamatan',
]);
```

Comment: thank you sir, its work now. But i wonder in other seeder i do like that, dont use json_encode, and its still work. ```'fields' => [[ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'jumlah', 'title' => 'Jumlah', ]],```

Comment: there may be a caster in the model, the caster will cast the data before the insertion https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting